# Using WAS liberty, need to set verbose GC

Tags: websphere-liberty, verbosegc

Need to configure verbose GC for WAS liberty profile.

How to set log file size, roll over count for the verbose GC log files.

Answer (score 3):

First hit on google for "websphere liberty verbose gc" describes exactly what you are asking for.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21596474

TL:DR

Put a `jvm.options` file in your server directory (next to the server.xml) with the following contents:

```
-verbose:gc
-Xverbosegclog: <path to file><filename>
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation 
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=<number of files> 
-XX:GCLogFileSize=<size>
```

Comment: -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation 
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=<number of files> 
-XX:GCLogFileSize=<size>

this doesnt work.